# Why is there suddenly a flood of Close votes in the review queue?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

There's been a greater than normal number of questions in the Close Votes review queue of late.

Some are in there for good reason. However, a large number of them also appear to be on-topic, have answers, and even have upvotes. Their only sins appears to be that they're old and they don't have an accepted answer.

They are, by and large, voted as "Unclear what you're asking". I'm not sure how that can be a valid close reason when there are upvotes and multiple answers. Obviously *someone* understood what was being asked.

What's going on?

---

Here are a few examples:

- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/close/96946
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/close/96881
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/close/96885

Comment: I agree that this is pointless.  Asking for clarification on ancient questions and then VTCing because that information is not given is not productive.

Comment: We're getting *slightly* more participation in the queues, which is good, but I'd love it it more people got involved with it to help democratize the situation you've mentioned.  I'd prefer to get myself out of the queue almost completely, but that hasn't been feasible in 4+ years.

Comment: @pnuts ?? It's a useful close reason, it's just not meant to be a "catch all" as you have coined it.  When I had asked people to use prefab close reasons, it was to keep better track of things such as the number of web development questions that were being asked rather than to abolish custom close reasons entirely.

Comment: Just a bystander, but could you provide some links to these reviews for examples? I don't have enough rep to review close votes, but reading pnuts' comment above, I'm afraid there's a misunderstanding because you mentioned that "*there are upvotes and multiple answers*".

Answer (score 7):

Possibly because there's a hat you can earn for being involved in the closing of questions:

[Ooh, Shiny](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304345/59303)

Expect the queue to settle down once people have won the hat or when Winterbash is over for this year.

Comment: I hate Winterbash.